# Generating JWT token with JwtUtil class in Spring Boot resulting in NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jwt

trying to implement a jwt based authentication for specific end points , but not able to import many of the packages , like in security config , cant able to extend my class with extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , which gives many of the built in functions , jwt dependency used for this is :

io.jsonwebtoken
jjwt
0.11.0

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in class: public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, instead you can create class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/testAPI").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new 
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        UserDetails userDetails = User
                .withUsername("vinod")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("singh"))
                .authorities("read").build();
        userDetailsService.createUser(userDetails);
        return userDetailsService;
    }

}
```